# Reading in a file stream inside a thread function c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, fstream

I'm working on a class project and am running into trouble getting my threads to read completely through a file. I can get them to get through the first word or two, then they stop and don't output anything. In my `main`, after I have joined the threads, `file.eof()` is returning true. Does anyone have any suggestions on why this might be happening or how to fix it?

(The project is to use alternating threads to "sort" vowels and consonants from a phrase in a file; I cannot use mutex, which is why there is a turn variable)

```
void cons(){
cout << "Turn is " << turn << endl; //outputs "Turn is 0"
    while (!file.eof()){
        if (turn == false){
            char c = word.at(0);
            if (c != 'A' || c != 'E' || c != 'I'|| c != 'O'|| c != 'U'){
                cout << "Consonant Thread: " << word << '\n';
                file >> word;
             }
    turn = true;
    }
    this_thread::yield();
    }
}

void vowel(){
    while (!file.eof()){
    if (turn == true){
        char c = word.at(0);
        if (c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I'|| c == 'O'|| c == 'U'){
        cout << "Vowel Thread: " << word << '\n';
        file >> word;
    }
    turn = false; //keeps track of thread turn to make sure the correct one is running
    }
    this_thread::yield();
    }
    }
```

Above is an example of one of my functions, the other is similar, but with c == 'Vowel"

My main looks like this

```
ifstream file;
string word;
bool turn = true; //true for vowel, false for cons
bool done = false;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
{
    file.open("phrase.txt");
    file >> word;

    if (file.eof()){
        done = true;
    }

    std::thread vowelThread(vowel); //passing vow function 
    std::thread consThread(cons); //passing cons function


    cout << file.eof() << endl; //returns true

    file.close();

    vowelThread.join();
    consThread.join();

    cout << (file.eof()) << endl; //returns true
}
```

To help clarify the problem, here's an example of what the code should do. Inside the .txt file `"phrase.txt"`, theres a simple phrase like `"Operating Systems Class Starts In The Evening"` The output should be `Vowel Thread: Operating` `Consonant Thread: Systems` `Consonant Thread: Class` etc, etc until the file has been read through

Any help would be appreciated, including resources about threads or suggestions to help my code. Thank you in advance!

Comment: file is an `std::fstream` ? where do you define `word`? please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you cannot use synchronization primitives, you cannot use concurrency. Pretty unclear what you hope to gain from using multiple threads here anyway.

Comment: I added my global variables to help clarify this. file is an ifstream global variable. Word is also a global variable. So are turn and done. They are global so they can be accessed by the thread.

Comment: To help clarify the problem, here's an example of what the code should do. Inside the .txt file "phrase.txt", theres a simple phrase like "Operating Systems Class Starts In The Evening" The output should be Vowel Thread: Operating Consonant Thread: Systems Consonant Thread: Class etc, etc until the file has been read through

Comment: @rhymeswithsilver you give us the output of the vowel thread function while you do not provide the function definition of `vowel` and expect us to imagine it based on your provided definition of `cons`. This is not how SO works, please provide a MCVE. I'd like to know why this question was upvoted..

Comment: @user Ive gone ahead and added it (I mentioned it was very similar to cons, so I thought it would be rather redundant to add both) but if it helps its there now! This is also my first time posting, so Im still getting used to how much information is needed and what people are looking for when they answer

Comment: @rhymeswithsilver The question is now correct (afaik). On a side note using turn across threads the way you do is better done using the `std::atomic` header (considering you cannot use mutex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem in your code is that the `main` thread closes the file while the two other thread work on it, it is no surprise that the `eof` bit gets set (threads can no longer access the closed `file`).
The proper way to correct this is to close the `file` after your threads have returned (that is after each threads returns from `join()`) however your program is still left with a major flaw which is how you designed the `cons` function and your logical `||` use which i have replaced by `&&` for obvious reasons.

```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    {
        file.open("phrase.txt");
        file >> word;

    if (file.eof()){
        done = true;
    }

    std::thread vowelThread(vowel); //passing vow function 
    std::thread consThread(cons); //passing cons function


    cout << file.eof() << endl; //returns true

    //file.close(); <- closes file while your threads work on it, thus the eof bit is set

    vowelThread.join();
    consThread.join();
    file.close();
    cout << (file.eof()) << endl; //returns true
}
```

and `cons`

```
void cons() {
    cout << "Turn is " << turn << endl; //outputs "Turn is 0"
    while (!file.eof()) {
        if (turn == false) {
            char c = word.at(0);
            if (c != 'A' && c != 'E' && c != 'I' && c != 'O' && c != 'U') {
                cout << "Consonant Thread: " << word << '\n';
                file >> word;
            }
            turn = true;
        }
        //this_thread::yield();
    }
}
```

On a side note now that you have seen the mistake in `cons` you will probably understand why I insisted that you provide every function and not ask us to deduce one function from the other.

There is one last problem (note that there are several flaws in your code which I do not address in order to stay on topic) : The last word `Evening` is not outputed because when `cons` prints `The` it then loads `Evening` into `word` and the `eof` bit is set which means the `vowel` thread doesn't get to enter your vowel output code. This is a design flow which I am sure you will know how to address.

If you need further precisions please do note hesitate to comment on my answer.

Comment: thank you! that makes sense. And yeah, the code definitely needs cleaned up a little bit because I've been poking at it and trying to figure it out, and absolutely, most of the little things you've mentioned are things I've just missed or haven't been thought through enough when I was writing it so they should be fairly simple to fix. Thank you again :)

Comment: @rhymeswithsilver Great, you are welcome. Now that your question fills all the requested criterias i also upvoted it.